# Credible intervals on parameter estimates do not contain zero, but inclusion of predictor does not improve model fit

Tags: bayesian

I am fitting Bayesian ordinal cumulative probit regression models (what a mouthful). I am new to this technique, but it seems to be what I need. I fit a model using a probit link function and including random intercepts to account for clustering (of participant responses).

I also fit another simpler model which does not contain the key interaction of interest. When I compare the WAIC, the simpler model has a lower WAIC. Moreover, the inclusion of my parameters of interest do not improve predictive accuracy on a test set in LOO cross validation.

Can I trust the parameter estimates and their credible intervals even though it seems that the inclusion of my variable of interest does not improve overall model fit?

BTW, I am using `brms` in R.

Comment: Maybe this says something about your prior?

Comment: I'm using brms default uninformative priors